# Change row content by ID. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JS code below:

```
var color = "red";

for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += ('<tr>' +
                                                        '<td>' + i + '</td>' + 
                                                        '<td>' + color + '</td>' +
                                                    '</tr>')
}
```

This creating me table:

```
1 red
2 red
3 red
...
```

What i need is to change color only for i 2. 
I mean after table created i want to change color only for i = 2 to get result:

```
1 red
2 blue
3 red
...
```

Change content of row by ID. 
Can you please suggest how to do this ?

Comment: Why can't you set the color to blue at the table creation process? With something like `'<td>' + (i === 2 ? "blue" : "red") + '</td>'`

Comment: it needs to work dynamically in real time

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You described your condition: i=2...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID for your TDs ... like below

```
var color = "red";
for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += ('<tr>' +
                                                    '<td>' + i + '</td>' + 
                                                    '<td id=td'+i+'>' + color + '</td>' +
                                                '</tr>')
}
```

then you can select any TD by its ID:

```
document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = "blue"
```

Comment: did you meant `'<td id="td'+i+'">'` instead of `'<td id=td'+i+'>'`? `<td id=td1>` is not a valid html node

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript Solution:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var secondRow = content.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
var colorCell = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];

colorCell.innerHTML = 'blue';
```

jQuery Solution:

```
$('#content tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text('blue');
```